# how to structure my iphone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to understand how to proceed with multiple views applications .
if i want that the user put information . For exemple , in a first view he will put a deparature date , in a second viw , he will put a return date .
how should i organize my classes ? Should i make a class ArrivalInformations and 2 xib file , When the user put the information in the first , i change the xib ? and create a delagate to get this informations ?

i'm not sur that i can do this , i just thinking .
Help please

Comment: Go through some iOS tutorials.  They are all over the place online.  They are a great starting place for learning iOS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a list of the whole data that your application is going to deal with. If you are done with that. Then take a plain paper and draw the views and the data that you are going to ask the user to input in each view. Then design your sqlite3 database. Then you move on to the communication between different views and how to put the data that the user inputs from different views into the sqlite3 db. If you want to discuss things in more detail, you can reach me at sayeedhussain19@gmail.com with your idea. I will help you design the architecture of your application.

Comment: For a pretty bad question this is actually a pretty decent answer.